# Problem starting Android Studio on Elementary Hera

Tags: release-hera, java, android-studio, jdk

I've gone through the steps of installing jdk, jre, etc. on Elementary OS Hera, based on **Ubuntu 18.04**. I downloaded Android Studio, extracted, gave the correct permissions, etc. but when running it I get some errors

**sh ./studio.sh**

```
Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:193)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1452)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.java:2337)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.scheduleInitUi(StartupUtil.java:401)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:192)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1399)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1396)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1429)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1312)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:326)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    ... 1 more

-----
Your JRE: 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04 amd64 (Ubuntu)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:621)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:317)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:270)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.logAndExit(StartupAbortedException.java:86)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.processException(StartupAbortedException.java:34)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:193)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

When running **java -version** I get this

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode)
```

I'm almost sure I've installed all the 64b. packages of each (jdk, jre)

I've also tried **sudo update-alternatives --config java**
I get these options (but Android Studio won't launch on any)

```
Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa java (que provee /usr/bin/java).

  Selección   Ruta                                            Prioridad  Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      modo automático
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      modo manual
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      modo manual
```

Thanks for any suggestion you can give me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the “headless” version of OpenJDK was installed. You should be able to resolve it like this:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Once installed, be sure the correct alternative is selected with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```